# Name and lastname search functions won't work. Why?

Tags: c, function

I made a function as my project and name search/lastname search functions are not working and giving a runtime error. I can't really see the mistake. So what's wrong it?

Also ID and Mark search system has some bugs with them, whenever you search for an ID it also brings mark = 0, also if you search for Mark, it will bring ID = 0.

Full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Student
{
    long long int id;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int mark;
} student;

void
storeRecord()
{
    FILE *fp;

    printf("\nEnter Student Details:\n\nID number: ");
    scanf_s("%lld",&student.id);

    printf("\nName:");
    scanf_s("%19s",student.firstname);

    printf("\nSurname:");
    scanf_s("%19s",student.lastname);

    printf("\nMark(0 - 100 integer) : ");
    scanf_s("%d",&student.mark);

    fp = fopen("studentfile.txt","a+"); /* check if the file was opened */
    if (fp == NULL)
        return;
    fprintf(fp, "\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
        student.id, 
        student.firstname, 
        student.lastname, 
        student.mark);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("A student record has been added successfully...\n");
    getchar();
}

int
compareStudentsById(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (lhs.id == rhs.id);
}

int
compareStudentsByName(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (strcmp(lhs.firstname, rhs.firstname) == 0);
}

int
compareStudentsByLastame(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (strcmp(lhs.lastname, rhs.lastname) == 0);
}

int
compareStudentsByMark(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (lhs.mark == rhs.mark);
}

void
printStudent()
{
    printf("\nThe record is found.\n");
    printf("\nID: %lld\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nMark: %d \n",
        student.id,
        student.firstname,
        student.lastname,
        student.mark
    );
}

void
searchStudent(int(*compare)(struct Student,struct Student), const char *const name, const char *const lastname, long long int id, int mark)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   found;
    int   matches;


    if (name != NULL)
        printf("Searching record with Name = %s.\n", name);
    if (lastname != NULL)
        printf("Searching record with Surname = %s.\n", lastname);
    if (id != -1)
        printf("Searching record with ID   = %lld.\n", id);
    if (mark != -1)
        printf("Searching record with Mark   = %d.\n", mark);

    found = 0;
    fp    = fopen("studentfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("IO error\n");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        struct Student other;

        if (name != NULL)
            strcpy(other.firstname, name);
        if (lastname != NULL)
            strcpy(other.lastname, lastname);

        other.id = id;
        other.mark = mark;
        matches  = fscanf(fp,"\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
            &student.id, 
            student.firstname, 
            student.lastname, 
            &student.mark);

        if (matches == 4)
            found = (compare(student, other) != 0);

    } while ((matches == 4) && (found == 0));

    if (found != 0)
        printStudent(); 
    else
        printf("Not found...\n");

    getchar();
}

void
searchStudentByName()
{
    char studentname[20];

    printf("\nEnter student first name: ");
    scanf_s("%19s", studentname);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByName, studentname, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

void
searchStudentById()
{
    long long int id;

    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf_s("%lld", &id);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsById, NULL, NULL, id, NULL);
}

void
searchStudentByLastname()
{
    char studentlastname[20];

    printf("\nEnter student surname: ");
    scanf_s("%19s", &studentlastname);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByLastame, NULL, studentlastname, NULL, -1);
}

searchStudentByMark()
{
    int mark;

    printf("\nEnter Mark: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &mark);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByMark, NULL, NULL, NULL, mark);
}

int main()
{

    int choice;

    choice = 0;
    while (choice != 5)
    {
        printf("\n\tC PROGRAM OF STUDENT DATABASE SYSTEM"); 
        printf("\n1 -> Store a new record in database\n");
        printf("2 -> Search a student record by Student First Name\n");
        printf("3 -> Search a student record by ID\n");
        printf("4 -> Search a student record by Surname\n");
        printf("5 -> Search a student record by Mark\n");
        printf("6 -> Quit Student Database");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");

        scanf_s("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case  1:
            storeRecord();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchStudentByName();
            break;
        case 3:
            searchStudentById();
            break;
        case 4:
            searchStudentByLastname();
            break;
        case 5:
            searchStudentByMark();
            break;
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: Please don't post full code. Please reduce your problem down.

Comment: @Dai I don't know the exact location of problem. So I just put the whole thing.

Comment: @luliu Unhandled exception at 0x6583f5cf in proje10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00460000.

Comment: For a start you could look at the warnings generated by the compiler. You are assigning `NULL` to a `long long int`, just use 0. To explain: `NULL` is a pointer value. So you are trying to assign a pointer to a variable. Don't use `NULL` to things that aren't pointers.

Comment: Please switch on all warnings on your compile. This will also tell you to look at this line `scanf_s("%19s", &studentlastname);`. Can you see what's wrong with it? (hint: look at the declaration of laststudentname)

Comment: You're determining whether to search by `id` and `mark` by checking whether they're `-1`, but when you don't want to use them you're passing `NULL` (not proper for non-pointers, but will likely set them to 0).

Comment: In this case: %s/NULL/0/g :-)

Comment: @DirkKoopman I guess I'm blind still can't fix it. If you can fix it could you please show me what have you done?

Comment: On my compiler I get a warning like: `format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’`, which is not to say I have solved the base problem, but this is a likely candidate.

Comment: @DirkKoopman whenever I integrated lastname function, it crashed firstname function. Also adding up Mark function killed Lastname function. (Don't know if it helps)

Comment: Oh go on then: remove the & from the `scanf_s("%19s", &studentlastname)`

Comment: When you call `searchStudent()`, pass `-1` instead of `NULL` for `mark` and `id` when you don't want to search by them.  Passing `NULL` is like passing `0`, and `searchStudent()` checks those fields for `-1`, not for `0`.

Comment: @DirkKoopman still; Unhandled exception at 0x6583f5cf in proje10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00eb0000.

Didn't change anything at all :<

Comment: Just compiled it with all the warnings removed and a couple of `#define` to fixed the M$isms and it works for me.

Comment: @Dirk Koopman in VC `scanf_s()` works with or without the `&` before `studentlastname`. I know this because I checked with `printf("%s",studentlastname)` which won't have worked if `scanf_s()` stored the input in the "wrong" location. But only in the case of a string.

Comment: Note: `fscanf(fp,"\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", ...` does the same as `fscanf(fp,"%lld%s%s%d ",` or `fscanf(fp,"%lld %s %s %d ",` or ...  Those `'\n'` and `'\t'` are not needed and they match any white-space

Comment: `scanf_s("%19s", &studentlastname);`  needs **2** parameters after the format: size and buffer ( I forget the order).

Comment: studentlastname is a pointer. &studentlastname is a pointer to an array of pointers. They are not the same thing and is **precisely** the sort of thing that will cause the sort of exception you are getting. You are saying use the pointer stored in the first 4 bytes of that char array. Those 4 bytes are characters, not a pointer.

Comment: @DirkKoopman I've also fixed all the errors and removed & from those parts but... this program will make me a murderer.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. It's fun if you don't weaken.

Comment: @DirkKoopman yeah, that's pretty true. I guess, I should try hard now. If you can solve it could you please answer the fixed code? Before I forget, thanks for all the work.

Comment: @Dirk Koopman in VC both `scanf_s()` and `printf()` work correctly for a string with or without the `&`, please try it and see.

Comment: @Weather Maybe so, but that doesn't make it correct. I have a working program. I am new here, do I post it as an answer or just post a diff (which is nearly as long).

Comment: @DirkKoopman if you fixed my awful code, you can post it as an answer. I will put a green tick and you will get score from it. If you're talking about your own code, I don't know.

Comment: @DirkKoopman as you wrote "It's fun if you don't weaken." Post what you feel is a good answer and see.

Comment: @DirkKoopman it's really funny and I didn't weaken! I won!
Code is working now somehow.

But now, how to fix it? (There are some unwanted extra friends)
[Click me to look image on IMGUR](http://i.imgur.com/5FZJH8D.png)

Comment: @WeatherVane could you please check the image that I posted on the comment just above. The only problem left inside is, that.

Comment: @WonderfulC Your remaining problem is because you're passing 0 for `id` and `mark` when you call `searchStudents()` but don't want to search by those fields.  Use -1 instead, since that's what you check for inside `searchStudents()`.

Comment: @Dmitri fixed it with a small trick. system("cls");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had compiled this code with warnings switched on (as everyone should do) and fixed the warnings, then this (amended) program would have mostly worked. Search by Mark works but ends the program. I'll leave that as something for you to fix.

```
void
printStudent()
{
    printf("\nThe record is found.\n");
    printf("\nID: %lld\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nMark: %d \n",
        student.id,
        student.firstname,
        student.lastname,
        student.mark
    );
}

void
searchStudent(int(*compare)(struct Student,struct Student), const char *const name, const char *const lastname, long long int id, int mark)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   found;
    int   matches;


    if (name != 0)
        printf("Searching record with Name = %s.\n", name);
    if (lastname != 0)
        printf("Searching record with Surname = %s.\n", lastname);
    if (id != -1)
        printf("Searching record with ID   = %lld.\n", id);
    if (mark != -1)
        printf("Searching record with Mark   = %d.\n", mark);

    found = 0;
    fp    = fopen("studentfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        printf("IO error\n");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        struct Student other;

        if (name != NULL)
            strcpy(other.firstname, name);
        if (lastname != NULL)
            strcpy(other.lastname, lastname);

        other.id = id;
        other.mark = mark;
        matches  = fscanf(fp,"\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
            &student.id, 
            student.firstname, 
            student.lastname, 
            &student.mark);

        if (matches == 4)
            found = (compare(student, other) != 0);

    } while ((matches == 4) && (found == 0));

    if (found != 0)
        printStudent(); 
    else
        printf("Not found...\n");

    getchar();
}

void
searchStudentByName()
{
    char studentname[20];

    printf("\nEnter student first name: ");
    scanf("%19s", studentname);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByName, studentname, 0, 0, 0);
}

void
searchStudentById()
{
    long long int id;

    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%lld", &id);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsById, 0, 0, id, 0);
}

void
searchStudentByLastname()
{
    char studentlastname[20];

    printf("\nEnter student surname: ");
    scanf("%19s", studentlastname);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByLastame, 0, studentlastname, 0, -1);
}

searchStudentByMark()
{
    int mark;

    printf("\nEnter Mark: ");
    scanf("%d", &mark);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByMark, 0, 0, 0, mark);
}

int main()
{

    int choice;

    choice = 0;
    while (choice != 5)
    {
        printf("\n\tC PROGRAM OF STUDENT DATABASE SYSTEM"); 
        printf("\n1 -> Store a new record in database\n");
        printf("2 -> Search a student record by Student First Name\n");
        printf("3 -> Search a student record by ID\n");
        printf("4 -> Search a student record by Surname\n");
        printf("5 -> Search a student record by Mark\n");
        printf("6 -> Quit Student Database");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");

        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case  1:
            storeRecord();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchStudentByName();
            break;
        case 3:
            searchStudentById();
            break;
        case 4:
            searchStudentByLastname();
            break;
        case 5:
            searchStudentByMark();
            break;
        case 6: 
            goto lend;
        }
    }
lend:;
    return 0;
}
```

Hint: add a `default` clause with error message to the `switch(choice)` and change the `if (choice != 5)` to a better test.

Comment: Have you changed **ALL** the `NULL`s to 0 (zero)?

Comment: Fixed NULL's to 0 and fixed warnings, it's a big no sir. Won't work.

Comment: If you have some kind of `diff` command in windows then compare my version with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple usages of scanning a string like `scanf_s("%19s", ...);`  are incorrect.

1. Do not use & before `studentlastname`.
2. Also pass the size of the buffer.  This is the key difference between `scanf()` and `scanf_s()`: Sizes passed for `char *` arguments.  A seg fault or other odd behavior may occur without the proper parameters.
3. Check the result of `scanf_s()`

   ```
   char studentname[20];
   // scanf_s("%19s", &studentlastname);
   if (1 != scanf_s("%s", studentlastname, sizeof studentlastname)) {
     Handle_Error();
   }
   ```
4. IMO: Do not use `scanf()` nor `scanf_s()` for any user input.  Instead use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or `sscanf_s()`, etc.

   ```
   char studentname[20];
   char buffer[2 * sizeof studentname + 2];  // I like 2x buffers
   if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
     Handle_EOF();
   } 
   if (1 != sscanf("%19s", studentlastname)) {
     Handle_Error();
   }
   // or
   if (1 != sscanf_s("%s", studentlastname, sizeof studentlastname)) {
     Handle_Error();
   }
   ```

Changing from `scanf()` to `fgets()` really works best if **all** user input is changed this way, including those getting numbers.

5. `int main()` --> `int main(void)`  @Dirk Koopman
6. If the final `getch()` needed for your environment,  if not consider deleting it.
7. BTW Good exit strategy with checking the result of `matches = fscanf(fp,...` and good code did not use `feof()`.

Comment: 1. Removed (Done)
2. Got it.
3. Changing it won't create an error but also won't do a search.
4. Replacing all scanf_s()'s with sscanf() occurs infinite loop and fgets() brings error.

Comment: It is not suggested to change `scanf_s` with `sscanf()`, but to read user input with `fgets()` and _then_ parse the buffer with `sscanf_s()`.

Comment: Add a case 6 to main and remove the superfluous `getch()`

Comment: Used scanf() on each scanf_s() and FIXED!